# Bootstrap 3 jQuery offset javascript error

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

The following function is throwing an error in the console window of my browser when the page loads:

```
function getRight() {
    return ($(window).width() - ($('[data-toggle="popover"]').offset().left + $('[data-toggle="popover"]').outerWidth()))
  }
```

The error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'left' of undefined
    at getRight (application.js:12)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (application.js:30)
    at j (jquery.js:3099)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.js:3211)
    at Function.ready (jquery.js:3417)
    at HTMLDocument.I (jquery.js:3433)
getRight @ application.js:12
(anonymous) @ application.js:30
j @ jquery.js:3099
fireWith @ jquery.js:3211
ready @ jquery.js:3417
I @ jquery.js:3433
```

The page is loading this jQuery:

https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js

Comment: are you running the code at dom ready?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically (without seeing the relevant HTML) the element you are trying to get the offset for, doesn't exist:

`$('[data-toggle="popover"]')`

Comment: It was referencing an element that I did not use in the template I downloaded.  Thanks!